# Replay Protected Memory Block - eMMC

Tags: embedded

I'm a beginner. I was reading about `Replay Protected Memory Block` in `eMMC` and understood about its main purpose. It is a specific memory area which is in an authenticated and replay protected manner. But, I'd like to know practically what kind of data requires that kind of memory area, with respect to embedded devices. Whether the booting related configurations? or read-only registers? or anything else?

Answer (score 11):

eMMC has separate partitions defined for BOOT, RPMB and User data.
Mostly, BOOT and RPMB are configured as  SLC while general partition can be configured as SLC or MLC, once in its lifetime.

> But, I'd like to know practically what kind of data requires that kind
>   of memory area, with respect to embedded devices.Whether the booting
>   related configurations? or read-only registers? or anything else?

Data, which should be secured enough resides here. Booting related configs are stored in the partition reserved for the Boot.

There are certain data, like,

1. DRM Content protection keys,
2. OEM provided/Specific security Keys,

which will of high commercial importance, on loss/disclosure of which may bring heavy penalty will be stored here.

Comment: Replay protection is not at all about secrecy, it is where to store counters (like a pin code failure counter) so that an attacker cannot just dump memory, try a few pins, flash memory back and get all its tries again. But it does not prevent reading.

Comment: I'd like also it helps to implement anti rollback features for trusted application, secured os, etc.